# Can not access variables in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

New to Codeigniter framework. I am trying to simply read user information from the database and show the result in a table in the view. (I have 6 pages in my website that in each page I want to show some user data)

default Controller:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home') {

        $this->load->helper('url');

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('pages/' . $page);
    }

    public function getUsers(){
            $data= array();
            $this->load->model('model_users');
            $data['users'] = $this->model_users->getUsers1();
            $this->load->view('pages/view_users', $data);
        }
}
```

Model:

```
class Model_users extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {                             
        parent::__construct();

    }    
        function getUsers1(){            
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM user');
        if($query->num_rows()>0){             
            return $query->result(); 
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
    <table>
         <tr>
             <td><strong>user ID</strong></td>
         </tr>
<?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
         <tr>
             <td><?php echo $user->id; ?></td>
         </tr>
<?php } ?>
     </table>
```

Error:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: users

Filename: pages/view_users.php
```

Any suggestion on why this error occurs and how to solve it?

Comment: what is the url you are checking?

Comment: Need to use that line of code to allow pages to load.

Comment: might be your query returning no any records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't post a comment :/

You are getting error because you are directly accessing the view file from browser address bar as:

```
localhost/projectname/page/view_users
```

Please access your controller's action something like this one:

```
localhost/projectname/page/getUsers
```

**You should read about Routes as well**

Comment: Yes I will get the results in your suggested link however I do lose all the bootstrap and templates. I will only get an array on my screen containing the users information coming from the table.

Comment: You should write proper links in <link> tag as you will something like <link href= "<?php  echo base_url()?>/css/style.css" >

I mean to say, link properly to directory where css files are. Again insist you to read about Routes in MVC.

Comment: My website is working fine if I use localhost/projectname/view_users ... All I need is to find a way to make view_users.php to receive the $data. Any suggestion?

Comment: I do have my style links defined as you have suggested. The problem is that you suggested to access the functions in my URLs... that way I will not have access to any of my pages any more!

Comment: Try
localhost/book/page/getUsers

And add header view 
`public function getUsers(){
            $data= array();
            $this->load->model('model_users');
            $data['users'] = $this->model_users->getUsers1();
           $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('pages/view_users', $data);
        }`

Comment: now it is working fine thank you .... but 1 issue is up now ... When I type localhost/project name it automatically goes to home page ... and when I want to click on "View Users" button, where that button should be directed to? to the method? like this <a href="localhost/book/page/getUsers"?????

Comment: Yes in that case if you are using anchors `<a>` on "View Users" link. you should write something like that. BUT instead of writing localhost use `href="echo site_url('page/getUsers')"` function which is codeigniter's built in function for links.

if the answer will help you, please accept so that it will increase my reputation.

Comment: I am a bit confused now. In every website that was built with codeigniter, their URLs are always like localhost/projectName/controller/Viewfile.php but now you are saying I should go with localhost/projectName/controller/functionOfController and then keep loading the templates in each function that I write in controller ... can you please explain why you are suggesting that? I am trying to learn your approach in codeigniter.

Comment: waiting for you. Thanks.

Comment: @Haseeb I am still in conversation and waiting for Murtaza to respond back as I am stuck in some part of the code ...

Comment: @MurtazaBhurgri Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 2):

Please put this code in  **Controller**:

```
$this->load->view('pages/view_users',$data);
```

Comment: Just beat me by few second!!

Comment: I already have your recommendation in my current code ... but it is not working ...

Comment: I have typed the error at the end of the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Saty but still OP didn't get solution.

Comment: @Irfana remove this one **$data= array();** and try

Comment: are you sure that you are calling that function from the controller?

Comment: @PathikVejani I did not understand your question, could you please type your suggested code to call the function from the controller?

Comment: @PathikVejani no it's like localhost/projectname/page/view_users

Comment: can you see `view_users` function in `page` controller @Irfana

Comment: @PathikVejani view_users is not a function, it is a view that is called view_users.php under the pages folder that is why it is addressed as pages/view_users

Comment: @Irfana that is right. i am asking that how do you access by URL: http://localhost/projectname/page/getUsers

Comment: @PathikVejani this is how I access the page : localhost/projectname/page/view_users

Comment: @PathikVejani I am not sure what do you mean exactly but here is a copy paste of my URL in local host: http://localhost/book/view_users

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right. But in case when your query returns empty result then here `$users` became `NULL` so it will give error on view. Put `if` before `foreach`. See below code

```
    <table>
     <tr>
         <td><strong>user ID</strong></td>
     </tr>
     <?php
           if(!empty($users)){ foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
     <tr>
         <td><?php echo $user->id; ?></td>
     </tr>
     <?php }}else{ ?>
       <tr>
         <td>No record found</td>
     </tr>
     <?php } ?>
 </table>
```

**On Model**

```
class Model_users extends CI_Model {

function __construct() {                             
    parent::__construct();

}    
    function getUsers1(){            
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM user');
        if($query->num_rows()>0){             
            return $query->result(); 
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the modification you suggested, now it is still giving the error plus it is showing "No record found". Any suggestion?

Comment: @Irfana check your table. is there any records?

Comment: @PathikVejani yes there is records in my table.

Comment: @Irfana change this `return $query->result();` to `return $query->result_array();`

Comment: have you updated model too? and @PathikVejani: no need to change result to result_array

Comment: @PathikVejani I tried it and I still get an error saying that users is not defined in vew_users and at the same time as Vinie suggested I added the if statement and while I get the error I also get  "No record found"

Comment: @Vinie, yes updated the model as you suggested above.

Comment: add `var_dump($users);` before `if` and tell me what it is giving.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

You can do this:

```
 public function getUsers(){

            $this->load->model('model_users');
            $users = $this->model_users->getUsers1();
            $this->load->view('pages/view_users', compact('users');
        }
```

[Compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) is more clean and If you need to change in future, will be easy.

And to access your page: localhost/your_site/getusers

But, if you want to use this standard, use [Routes](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html). Because "getusers" in URL isn't beautiful.

Comment: I tried it with you code and then used localhost/book/getusers but it did not work.

Comment: Error is written at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

First try whether your array gives any result.

```
public function getUsers(){
            $this->load->model('model_users');
            $data['users'] = $this->model_users->getUsers1();
            print_r($data['users']);
        }
```

Comment: yes just checked and array is giving results and showing the table data. Problem is that the view page (view_users.php) is not receiving the $data from controller.